# Upgrading from Tomcat 6.0.18 gives new Exception

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

After upgrading from `Tomcat 6.0.18` to `Tomcat 6.0.36` I get some exceptions concerning a few JSP in my project.

Did they change the way Tomcat handles JSP ?

```
javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert PLA of type class java.lang.String to class java.lang.Long
```

Comment: It will be very kind of you to find the JSP fragment that produces this exception and to send it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seams that in `Tomcat 6.0.18` if you try to compare a `Long` to a `String` you get the result `false` while in `Tomcat 6.0.36/6.0.37` you get an `exception`.

If you try: `${2.33 == 'Does it work?'}`

In Tomcat 6.0.18 the output is: `false`

In Tomcat 6.0.36/6.0.37 the output is: `exception, cannot convert String to Long`

Answer (score 1):

We encountered an issue where Tomcat 6's startup parameters were sending in values with quotations instead of just the value.  This occurred between upgrading from 6.0.33 to 6.0.37.   Check and see if the long is quoted, like '2.33' instead of just 2.33.